# Can a common software slider input be patented if its specific function is appended in the patent request?

Tags: wo2017144926a1

Square and similar big payment processors having physical devices already using such techniques for years. These guys found something existing and try to patent it.

See:
https://squareup.com/help/us/en/article/5069-accept-tips-with-the-square-app

In reference to the patent: [WO2017144926A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2017144926A1)

Comment: That is an application, not yet a patent.

Comment: And their claim 1 has over 300 words in it. What they are trying to patent is more involved.

Answer (score 2):

The document you cited is only a patent application. It may or may not ever become a patent. Even if it does get granted, it is very likely the claims will become narrowed. That said, the first claim (and only independent claim) is quite lengthy.

> 1. Device for the implementation of cash-free payment, with the possibility of interactive tip input, which contains a server unit (3)
>      that may be connected to a financial service provider's (1) accounting
>      unit (la) via an information transmission channel (2), where the
>      server unit (3) has a data traffic gate (3a) connected to the
>      information transmission channel (2), a signal receipt input (3b) and
>      display output (3c), a payment card reader part-unit (3d), data input
>      part-unit (3e) and display (3f), the display output (3c) of the server
>      unit (3) is connected to the display (3f), and the signal receipt
>      input (3b) of the server unit (3) is connected to the payment card
>      reader part-unit (3d) and the data input part-unit (3e), characterised
>      by that the server unit (3) is coupled with a free data input unit
>      (10), the free data input unit (10) having at least two selecting
>      part-units (11) separated by a gap (T) and suitable for displaying
>      different signals (1 la, 1 lb), a selection-sensing member (13)
>      associated with the selecting part-unit (11) and a data transmission
>      part unit (14) connected to the selection-sensing member (13), and the
>      data transmission part unit (14) is connected to the signal receipt
>      input (3b) of the server unit (3), where the selecting part-unit (11)
>      has a screen (12), serving to display the given signals (11a, l ib),
>      with display zones (12a, 12b) separated by a gap (T) from each other
>      that are clearly associated with each of the given signals (11a, l
>      ib), where the screen (12) with the display zones (12a, 12b) has an
>      interactive data input touch screen at least in the vicinity of the
>      display zones (12a, 12b) with a sensing surface (12c) suitable for
>      changing at least one physical attribute of the display zones (12a,
>      12b), and the selection-sensing member (13) has selection transmission
>      lines (13a, 13b) in signal- transmission connection with the sensing
>      surface (12c) of the individual display zones (12a, 12b).

In order to infringe on this claim you would have to implement each and every step listed within it. As claims go this one is very complex and thus amenable to being circumvented. There are specific references to hardware so I don't see where your concern it that is it is patenting a "common software slider".

Comment: given it is so specific, why might this patent application be filed?

Comment: @bharal Who can say. Some individual inventors doing their own patent drafting tend to claim too narrowly. Some companies just want to amass a quantity of patents to threaten others or provide perceived protection.